# Transaction table in SQL to change format of final table

Tags: sql

I have a table in SQL..I want to convert into another format after summation.

The original table is as under:

```
          Transaction Data

          
          Date Location Sales
          01-Jan-2020 Hyderabad     25
          31-Jan-2020 Hyderabad     22
          11-0ct-2020 Bangalore     11
          25-Dec-2019 Bangalore     10
```

The final table I want is as

```
            Month Sales
            Ja20  47
            Oct20 11
            Dec19 10
```

The problem has to be done in SQL.I am new in SQL. Please guide me. Please don't ban me.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Scala is a programming language, which has nothing to do with your question, so I'm removing it from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the SQL dialect, there are ways to truncate to month and date. For instance, in Postgres we have [date_trunc](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date_trunc/).

```
SELECT
    date_trunc('month', date) AS month,
    SUM (sales) AS sales
FROM
    transaction_data
GROUP BY
    1
ORDER BY
    1;
```